# Objects Not Showing in Other Workspace Viewports, Only Default

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view, interface

I'm having this issue where my objects only show up in default view. When I switch to the other workspaces; UV editing, compositing, Nothing shows up at all; not even the cameras, lighting, either. The names show up in the outliner, but in the viewport of the other workspaces. Nothing.

- Tried changing Clipping Distance: Didn't work
- Tried to switch the interface windows around: Didn't Work
- I am Using Blender 2.79b
- I am in Cycles Mode, I don't care about Blender Internal Render
- I tried changing some of the windows to 3D view in the other workspaces: Didn't work
- I am using the Pie Menu add-on, idk if that could be a problem

[image: Default View It Shows]

[image: Nothing in UV Editing]

[image: Nothing in Compositing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in *Local View*, check your viewport label on the top left.

Local view is stored per viewport, so switching layouts or windows doesn't carry it over, though switching scenes in the viewport does.

Exit *Local View* mode to view your scene, either using <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> or in the 3D view header choose the menu option *View > View Global/Local* to toggle.

Comment: another problem, I'm using a keyboard w/o a numpad. is there an alternative hotkey?

Comment: Omg thank you so much. I was scared that I might lose my model. Much much thanks!

Comment: Check above, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

I know there should be a solution inside blender properties, but none of the above worked for me, so I deleted and added back the background images, and it is viewable now.