# Blender hiding all object but one in everything except default edit menu

Tags: rendering

I am trying to create a character, while trying to render out the image to a png, it hides all objects besides the head, and a side issue, the object is pitch black. I have tried restarting blender and turning on and off their render-ability. but neither worked, I don't know where to go from here, it would be nice if somebody was able to help. :I[image: 1][image: 3][image: 2]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111995/objects-not-showing-in-other-workspace-viewports-only-default/112001#112001