# My objects are invisible in blender 2.8, how to fix?

Tags: 3d-view, error

Until 3 weeks ago, blender 2.8 was normal. But now it is with these invisible objects, both in the viewport and in the render.

Already tried to switch to Eevee, Workbench and Cycles,
I also tried to load the factory options.

Blender 2.8,
Windows 10,
Intel core I3 6003U.
8Gb Ram[image]

[image]

Comment: Mine are too. (and I have the same system as you) And I've gotten no help from anyone.I asked this question already, but some jerk closed my thread. You can check out this thread and maybe get a little more information. https://blenderartists.org/t/object-always-see-through/1115094

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a version of Blender still in development.

Comment: @RayMairlot I would like to vote to open this up again as 2.8 is live and I am having the exact same issues at least with the Layout Screen.

Comment: Actually, found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51132/objects-disappearing-in-viewport-but-visible-in-outliner) and it solved my issues. Might want to link the questions though as they are related I would imagine.