# Objects don't appear in viewport but are not hidden in the outliner

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, outliner

Hello I'm not sure why this issue is happening but when I open the model in 3.0 all the objects show up but it has no textures, when i open it in 3.4.1 the textures show up but not all of the mesh appears. I'm not sure why this issue is happening. The first image was in 3.4.1 and the second is in 3.0. The last image of the outliner is to show that none of the meshes are hidden. I had two other friends test it out and it works perfectlly fine for them. I'm not sure if it's a setting I have or not. Here is the file for anyone to test. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LcYLkITcRQwJQDBJz_4bKlAlC0X8ta95/view?usp=share_link

This issue has happened with many other models I've used. I don't understand how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See if any of this helps you:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51132/148948

Answer (score 2):

The reason the textures are not working in the older version of Blender are those *Mix* nodes in the materials:

[image: new mix nodes]

These are relatively new, they are not simple *Mix RGB* nodes like they were before, they are now more versatile and can be switched to either *Float*, *Vector* or *Color*, which the old *Mix RGB* nodes couldn't. Therefore they appear as "Undefined" when you look at them in the older *Shader Editor*:

[image: undefined nodes]

So if you wanted to open it with the older version you had to replace those *Mix* nodes with the old *Mix RGB* nodes. You can do this in the older version of Blender, but there is also a trick to get the deprecated nodes in the new version: If you have the *Node Wrangler* addon enabled and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> and drag from one node with color output to another to mix them automatically, then *Node Wrangler* will bring up the old *Mix RGB* node which works in the new and old Blender version. (Although I think it's funny that Blender seems to know that the "Undefined" nodes should have color in/out and the color and mix factors are stored in there, but still it doesn't produce a result.)

That's for the material. Now to the other problem which seems to be unrelated and should rather be asked with another question thread - although I guess it's a bug in your Blender. Because when I open your file in my Blender 3.4.1, everything looks fine:

[image: freddy complete]